# Differences between the PlayStation 3 and Xbox 360 versions of GTA 5/Online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, version-differences, grand-theft-auto-online

I want to play *GTA V* and *GTA Online*, but I don’t have a supported console yet. Now I wonder which console (hence which *GTA V* version) I should buy (assuming I’m not interested in any other games on these consoles).

**What are the differences between the *PlayStation 3* and the *Xbox 360* versions?**

I’m not interested in minor graphical differences. Instead:

- Any **gameplay** differences? Anything added/missing in one version?
- Any **game mechanics** differences? E.g. does the save system work the same?
- Any **performance** differences? Is one version running more smoothly?
- Any **online social** differences? Ingame (voice) chat, friend lists etc.
- Is the **support** the same? E.g. do both version get the same updates, at the same time?
- And what about the current (and estimated) **online player base**? Does one version have potentially more online players?

Comment: I should be 99% the same in gameplay.

Answer (score -3):

Well, for the **PlayStation 3** you won't have to install content onto the console because the **PS3** uses Blu Ray. I'm an Xbox gamer, but you should probably go with the **PS3**.

Comment: This answer doesn't really answer Unor's question. This is just a basic answer. It needs more details.

Comment: You *do* have to install it on the PS3.  This is a really bad, and uneducated assumption.  Many PS3 games require installation.